# P5.js - combine two sketches, 2D and WEBGL, sitting one on top of the other

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to combine two p5.js sketches and have them as the website background, sitting one on top of the other. In particular, the first will be an ellipse reacting to a sound, and the second will be a rotating 3D object. I'd need for both of them to be positioned at the center of the canvas.

There's two problems I can't overcome when working with Instance Mode:

1. Starting from two 2D sketches, I'm not able to position one on top of the other. When try applying `p.canvas.style('z-index', '-1')` to the bottom one, this disappears.
2. When adding WEBGL as the third element of the canvas specs, the canvas disappears.

I'm therefore wondering if it's possible to achieve what mentioned above? If yes, is Instance Mode the right way to procede?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

As suggested I tried playing with createGraphics and worked!

Now I only have a problem left with the 3D model sitting on top of the 2D canvas. It seems like the transform functions react differently when I apply WEBGL in createGraphics - as if it doesn't recognise the axes' central point and changes the speed, perhaps?

Here's the Github repo (the model is somewhere there, just need to move the mouse around to make it appearing):

https://bianchinicecilia.github.io/XMAS-Web/

As you can see it seems like the center of the object is translated, I think.

It's not a problem of the model, as I tested it out in another simple WEBGL canvas. Here's the working example's GH repo:
https://bianchinicecilia.github.io/CreateGraphics/

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I would use instance mode if you need multiple sketches on the same page. But I would also look into using multiple p5.Graphics objects in the same sketch before resorting to using multiple sketches.

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for your kind reply! Exactly, I'll test Graphics now. I'm trying to combine these two examples by Shiffman. Hopefully it will work.
1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tTZlTq4Cxs
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNDc8KXWp9E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with extraCanvas.push() + extraCanvas.pop().

Here's the working draw function:

```
function draw() {
  //sound reaction
  background('#F4EDED');

  var vol = amp.getLevel();
  var diam = map(vol, 0, 0.3, 370, 600);

  fill('#FFFFFF');
  noStroke();
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, diam, diam);

  // obj

  extraCanvas.ambientLight(50);
  extraCanvas.directionalLight(255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 1);
  extraCanvas.noStroke();

  extraCanvas.push();

  extraCanvas.rotateZ(frameCount * 0.005);
  extraCanvas.rotateX(frameCount * 0.005);
  extraCanvas.rotateY(frameCount * 0.005);

  // Rotate in direction of mouse
  let posX = width/8;
  let posY = height/8;

  let angle = Math.atan2(mouseY-posY, mouseX-posX);

  // Rotate on MouseDrag
  /*let angle = 0;

  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    angle =  atan2(mouseY - height / 2, mouseX - width / 2);
  }*/

  extraCanvas.rotateX(angle);
  extraCanvas.rotateY(angle);
  extraCanvas.rotateZ(angle);

  //extraCanvas.translate(-100, 0, 0);
  extraCanvas.clear();
  extraCanvas.texture(kitten);
  extraCanvas.model(train);

  image(extraCanvas, 0, 0);

  extraCanvas.pop();

}
```

And here's the Reddit thread that explain the process:
https://www.reddit.com/r/p5js/comments/k2ydcp/combine_2_sketches_one_2d_one_webgl_and_make_them/